# How can I Create an explosive with everyday used chemicals?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, explosives

I would like to know How can i create a simple (Maybe Complex) Chemical that can be used as an explosive.

I would like to use it to blast A regular cardboard box.

Comment: Ammonium nitrate maybe?

Comment: Trying to synthesize explosives without the proper training and equipment is a really, really bad idea. You probably won't blow up a cardboard box, but your own hand or worse. I don't think questions about explosives from household chemicals belong here.

Comment: @MadScientist Actually I'm glad that these questions are asked (and answered) here, rather than on some obscure amateur pyromaniac sites.

Comment: If you don't mind a personal advice: Don't! First aid on explosion victims isn't fun for anyone involved.

Comment: Use potassium nitrate.

Comment: Note that, in addition to being extremely dangerous, in most jurisdictions it is a serious crime to prepare or use explosives without a permit. In some jurisdictions, it is even a crime to give instruction on preparation of explosives to an unauthorised person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends!

#### Can you regrow lost organs?

If you're genetically close to a newt and can easily regrow organs lost in an explosion, you should give triacetone triperoxide (TATP) a try. Cool an equimolar mixture of acetone and 50% hydrogen peroxide to 0 °C, add some drops of concentrated sulfuric acid and let it come to room temperature **without stirring**. After 24h, collect the precipitate and dry it **carefully**.

**TATP is extremely shock sensitive - one careless scratching and you're done - and has a Trauzl value similar to that of TNT!**

If you feel by now that you better shouldn't play with it: **You are right!**

#### What about a something less suicidal?

On contact with water, calcium carbide forms calcium hydroxide and releases ethyne:
$$\ce{CaC2 + 2 H2O -> Ca(OH)2 + C2H2 ^ }$$

This might be enough to burst a sealed container. Alternatively, you might consider to ignite a mixture of ethyne and air. **In any case, take care!**

Comment: Acetone peroxide is probably the most shock sensitive and dangerous-to-prepare of all the explosives that can be made according to the the constraints outlined so eloquently above. I find your suggestion of it, along with the notion of drying it, to be in poor judgment. If your looking to blow up a cardboard box and make a loud noise, why not consider containing dry ice inside a 2-liter, PETE bottle until it ruptures, using water as a catalyst. A louder, deeper boom and you still get to keep your hand if the 'explosion' goes of in it. Explosion can be defined as a rapid expansion of gasses.